# PHP Variable OR

Tags: php

Currently trying to do something if user has x role he shouldn't be allowed on the page and it should exit().

I currently have tried this

```
if ($role != 'Host' OR 'Admin') {
exit('You do not have permission to access this page!');}
```

But it keeps exiting even when the current user has the $role = Host or Admin.

In my mind this all makes sense but the code just doesn't work.

Comment: `if ($role != 'Host' OR 'Admin') {` should be `if ($role !== 'Host' || $role !== 'Admin') {`

Comment: @GuidoFaecke why can't I just use the OR statement too check both at once rather then repeating it?

Comment: Because `OR` is another way to do `||` - you could have `if ($var1 == "hello" OR $var2 == "goodbye")`, it doesn't know which var is which, only 2 separate checks

Comment: Shorthand that is exactly the same length

Comment: Each side of the OR statement must be a full statement. So `$role != 'Host' OR 'Admin'` can be read as `($role != 'Host') || 'Admin')`, so `Admin` will always be true. My favorite for checks like this is `if(!in_array($role, ['Host','Admin']))`. It's a little cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: It keeps giving me the exit function even when I have changed the code into @GuidoFaecke's answer.

Comment: In your version PHP check if `$role != 'Host'` is true OR `'Admin'` is `true`. Essentially these are 2 different comparisons.

Comment: Also, OR statements, only one has to be true, so even if $role is Admin, it's not Host, so it will hit the exit. you'd need AND, not OR

Comment: It's not uncommon for languages to require multiple tests for a single value rather than a single test for multiple values. It is less ambiguous and allows for some pretty complicated statements without the result getting interpreted in a way the user was not expecting.

Comment: @aynber that fixed it however I find it very strange. I don't really get why it should be AND and not OR.

Comment: Because on an OR clause, only 1 needs to match. For AND, all need to match. A role cannot be both Host and Admin, so one side of the OR statement will always fail. If you were using `if($role == 'Admin' || $role == 'Host')`, that's fine because you're trying to prove a positive. When you're trying to prove a negative, then you need to prove all of the clauses, since $role will either be Host OR Admin or none of the above, but if role is Host, then it's not Admin, and vice versa

Comment: Another way to look at it. Say $role is Host. `$role != 'Host'` is false. Great. Now it has to check the other side of the OR, and `$role != 'Admin'` is true. `false || true` is true because only one side needs to match. `false && true` is false, because they both need to match.

Comment: @CanO'Spam You need to enclose each statement with parenthesis because of the `or` operator precedence.

Comment: That actually makes so much sense, thanks @aynber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
if ($role != 'Host' AND $role != 'Admin') {
    exit('blabla');
}
```

But, it is better to put the allowed roles not directly into the condition but into an array, for instance.

```
$allowed_roles = ['Host', 'Admin'];
if (! in_array($role, $allowed_roles) {
    exit('blabla');
}
```

The main advantage of this is that you can store the allowed roles somewhere else but in your logical code, e.g. in a database or in a config file. And you can easily change the list without touching your program's logic.

And, to explain why your code always keeps exiting: The right hand side part of your `if ($role != 'Host' OR 'Admin')` is always true. That is because a non-empty string like 'Admin' will evaluate to true. That's why the part on the right hand side of the `OR` is always true, and so the whole expression is always true (`OR` means that only one of multiple conditions has to be true).

Comment: By the way: `OR` is not a variable, but a logical operator.

Comment: Please help Stack Overflow to combat redundant questions/content by flagging to close duplicate questions.  As a general rule, if you see a basic question asked after 2015, it has probably been asked and answers at least 5 times already.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint. I'll do so in future.